# How to invoke aligned new/delete properly?

Tags: c++, c++17, new-operator, delete-operator

How do I call `new` operator with alignment?

```
auto foo = new(std::align_val_t(32)) Foo; //?
```

and then, how to delete it properly?

```
delete(std::align_val_t(32), foo); //?
```

If this is the right form of using these overloads, why valgring complaining about mismatched free()/delete/delete[]?

Comment: The aligned versions are meant to be overloaded (e.g.: in your class) and are automatically called by operator `new` - you don't call them manually. See e.g.: the microsoft documentation for an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-alignednew?view=vs-2017#example

Comment: I dont see how you got to this conclusion. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: Which of the overloads are you referring to? All of the ones listed in that page are for *overloadable* operator `new`, not the default implemented ones

Comment: This one (item 3) `void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, std::align_val_t al);`

Comment: And how did you defined your `Foo` that it fulfills the criteria *"Called by non-array new-expressions to allocate storage required for a single object whose alignment requirement exceeds `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`"*?

Comment: I provide the alignment I want in the call to the `operator new`? nothing to do with  `Foo` definition, consider the `Foo` as `int`. I want my pointer to `int` to be aligned to 32 bytes. May I have it?

Comment: That is not how these overloads work. As described in the page you linked yourself they are called automatically when using `new` on a type that has a different `alignas` specifier (see e.g.: this article for details: https://www.bfilipek.com/2017/06/cpp17-details-clarifications.html#dynamic-memory-allocation-for-over-aligned-data). If you want to manually align you need to use [`std::aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc) (in combination with placement `new`)

Comment: Disagree, it is not what is written in the Bartek blog. If you call `new` the aligned overload will be called with `align_of` result as argument to the aligned `new`. No one says I cant call the overload to get aligned storage. As of aligned_alloc, this is what I use now (not sure what to do about your mention of placement new) and want to get rid of it since I have standard way to get aligned pointer

Comment: `operator delete(foo,std::align_val_t(32));`

Comment: @UnholySheep *"All of the [overloads] listed in that page are for overloadable operator `new`, not the default implemented ones"* The linked page says that *"The versions (1-4) are implicitly declared in each translation unit"*.

Comment: @UnholySheep Can you provide any reference for *"That is not how these overloads work."*? [This page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) simply says that *"If `placement_params` are provided, they are passed to the allocation function as additional arguments."* Despite the name, I don't see any requirements for what `placement_params` can be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

exist very basic principle - the memory free routine always must match to allocate routine. if we use mismatch allocate and free - run time behavior can be any: all can be random ok, or crash by run-time, or memory leak, or heap corruption.

if we allocate memory with aligned version of operator new

```
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, std::align_val_t al);
```

we **must** use the corresponding aligned version of operator delete

```
void operator delete  ( void* ptr, std::align_val_t al );
```

call `void operator delete  ( void* ptr );` here always must lead to run-time error. let simply test

```
    std::align_val_t al = (std::align_val_t)256;
    if (void* pv = operator new(8, al))
    {
        operator delete(pv, al);
        //operator delete(pv); this line crash, or silently corrupt heap
    }
```

why is aligned and not aligned version of `operator delete` always incompatible ? let think - how is possible allocate **align** on some value memory ? we initially always allocate some memory block. for return **align** pointer to use - we need adjust allocated memory pointer to be multiple align. ok. this is possible by allocate more memory than requested and adjust pointer. but now question - how free this block ? in general user got pointer not to the begin of allocated memory - how from this user pointer jump back to begin of allocated block ? without additional info this is impossible. we need store pointer to actual allocated memory before user returned pointer. may be this will be more visible in code typical implementation for aligned `new` and `delete` use [`_aligned_malloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2017) and [`_aligned_free`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-free?view=vs-2017)

```
void* operator new(size_t size, std::align_val_t al)
{
    return _aligned_malloc(size, static_cast<size_t>(al));
}

void operator delete  (void * p, std::align_val_t al)
{
    _aligned_free(p);
}
```

when not aligned `new` and `delete` use `malloc` and `free`

```
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete  (void * p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

now let look for internal implementation of [`_aligned_malloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2017) and [`_aligned_free`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-free?view=vs-2017)

```
void* __cdecl _aligned_malloc(size_t size, size_t alignment)
{
    if (!alignment || ((alignment - 1) & alignment))
    {
        // alignment is not a power of 2 or is zero
        return 0;
    }

    union {
        void* pv;
        void** ppv;
        uintptr_t up;
    };

    if (void* buf = malloc(size + sizeof(void*) + --alignment))
    {
        pv = buf;
        up = (up + sizeof(void*) + alignment) & ~alignment;
        ppv[-1] = buf;

        return pv;
    }

    return 0;
}

void __cdecl _aligned_free(void * pv)
{
    if (pv)
    {
        free(((void**)pv)[-1]);
    }
}
```

in general words `_aligned_malloc` allocate `size + sizeof(void*) + alignment - 1` instead requested by caller `size`. adjust allocated pointer to fit alignment , and **store** originally allocated memory before pointer returned to caller.

and `_aligned_free(pv)` call not `free(pv)` but `free(((void**)pv)[-1]);` - for **always another** pointer. because this effect of `_aligned_free(pv)` always another compare `free(pv)`. and `operator delete(pv, al);` always not compatible with `operator delete(pv);` if say `delete []` usual have the same effect as `delete` but align vs not align always run time different.

Comment: Theoretically we coulde've had a separate heap for aligned memory where the first address is always aligned.

Comment: @Qwertiy - but on which count of bytes ? 16 ? 32 ? 256 ? have separate heap for every possible 2^n ? then again we need special routine for free - how free can know with which heap need work ?

Comment: As you see aligns are always powers of 2, so it's just n heaps for 2^n. Now we need n linked lists - one per each power. When we allocate an alinged block we take it from the first nonempty list with enought ize of block. Tail (or beginning as an opposit version) of the block is splitted by powers of 2 and added to corresponding lists. Allognment is rarely used on data with size less then alignment.

Comment: @Qwertiy - anyway we need have special `_aligned_free` here which instead free to default crt heap, determinate to which aligned heap belong memory block and free to this heap. so code of `_aligned_free` even in this case (no stored pointer to begin of block before user returned pointer) must be different from `free`. and as result aligned delete will be different from non aligned

Comment: No, we can determine by initial adress and size.

Comment: @Qwertiy - yes, can determinate, but for this need special code, with usual not exist in `free`. possible make common implementation, but this will be cost by speed and special heap sizes - hold how many heaps ? what if user at all not require aligned malloc ? usual better have common heap and align usual allocations from it

Comment: Yep. Anyway manipulations with memory are not the fastest think in the code :)

Comment: Isn't it a Windows-only problem? Other popular os support [aligned_alloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) whose return value can be released with free. So, I guess, all the problems you mentioned aren't so unsolvable in general

Comment: @yrHeTateJlb in this case implementation of alloc/free always must be more complex than unconditional free given memory pointer

Comment: Well, it is implemented this way everywhere except windows

Comment: Ok, maybe not everywhere. I'm not familiar with every possible platform. But committee added function that requires complex free implementation, despite they care about portability and performance a lot. I infer this complexity is not a big deal

Answer (score 3):

The below syntax was the only one that worked for me to create and destroy an overaligned array, using clang-cl 13 on Windows 10 x64:

```
int* arr = new (std::align_val_t(64)) int[555];
::operator delete[] (arr, std::align_val_t(64));
```

For the same new operation, the below delete expression would not compile ("cannot delete expression of type 'std::align_val_t'):

```
delete[] (arr, std::align_val_t(64));
```

The below delete expression will compile, but then throws a runtime error ("
Critical error detected c0000374"):

```
delete[](std::align_val_t(64), blocks);
```